# In Neo4J , Loading a Parent Node is loading duplicate children with id=null

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Following is the model with `A`(UserN) and `B`(UserRoleN) as objects.

```
@NodeEntity()
public class UserN
{
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Relationship(type = "hasRole", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<UserRoleN> role;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setRole(List<UserRoleN> role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public List<UserRoleN> getRole() {
        return role;
    }
}


@NodeEntity()
public class UserRoleN
{
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getName() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }   
}
```

In the database, following is graph structure:

```
    A->B
```

While loading A, `session.load(A.class, id, 1)` , a total of 2 B-Objects are loading under A Object in which one of the B's ID is null and other B object ID is neo4j generated.

Unable to understand why the duplicate B is loaded where Database has only one B Object.

Comment: Please post the entire class for A and B or a simple unit test

Comment: Updated the model.